# BitBlt a bitmap onto a splash screen

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, bitmap

I am working on a splash screen for a simple Direct3D game and although the screen itself is created and destroyed properly, the `BITMAP` meant to be projected onto the splash screen isn't showing up. I have this so far:

```
//variable declarations
HWND splashWindow = NULL;
BITMAP bm;

//window procedure
LRESULT WINAPI SplashProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(splashWindow, &ps);
            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem);
            EndPaint(splashWindow, &ps);
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //initialize splash window settings
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); 
    wc.style         = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = SplashProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = NULL;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Splash Window";
    wc.hIconSm       = NULL;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    //create and draw the splash window
    HBITMAP splashBMP = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, "assets\\textures\\splash.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    GetObject(splashBMP, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    //^-splashBMP to bm - used here so the window has proper dimensions
    splashWindow = CreateWindow("Splash Window", NULL,
        WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (splashWindow == 0) return 0;

    ShowWindow(splashWindow, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(splashWindow);
    //after the game loads the splash screen is destroyed through DestroyWindow(splashWindow);
    //and splashBMP is released by calling DeleteObject(splashBMP);
```

Really, the only important code is `SplashProc` handling the `WM_PAINT` message.  The bitmap `bm` is loading fine shown through the window's 900x600 dimensions (same as splash.bmp).  However, that window is just a black screen instead of the herobrine face contained in splash.bmp xD

Comment: Heads up: I screwed up isolating the code.  wc.lpfnWndProc is no longer DefWindowProc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those where you've almost certainly stared at the code so long you missed the obvious.

You're creating `hdcMem`, and then immediately `BitBlt`ing to the splash screen. Between those you undoubtedly want a `SelectObject` to select your bitmap into `hdcMem`.

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(splashWindow, &ps);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

// You need to add this
HBITMAP oldBmp = SelectObject(hdcMem, splashBMP);    

BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// ...and this
SelectObject(hdcMem, OldBmp);

DeleteDC(hdcMem);
EndPaint(splashWindow, &ps);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've kind of avoided GDI until today... What exactly is the purpose of creating `oldBmp`?  Couldn't I just use splashBMP in SelectObject?

Comment: You're supposed to restore a DC to "pristine" condition (i.e., none of your "stuff" selected into it) before you delete it. To do that, you save the original bitmap and select it back into the DC before destroying the DC. I'm not sure how much real difference it makes, but that's what Microsoft says you should do.