# Image not displayed correctly with BitBlt

Tags: c, winapi

So I just started c yesterday, literally. Being as fresh as I can be, I tried a fairly simple task of displaying an image on top of my desktop. First i tried it with pixels:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    
    int a;
    int b;
    int x = 0;
    COLORREF clr =  RGB(200,100,30);
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    while (x != 1){
        for (a=0; a<20; a++){
            for (b=0; b<20; b++){
                SetPixel(dc,b,a, clr);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and it worked. Now I try to do it with entire image and it fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    
    int x = 0;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "neco.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 487, 456, LR_LOADFROMFILE); 
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    
    while (x != 1){
        BitBlt(dc,0,0,487,456,hBitmap,0,0,SRCPAINT);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I assume it reads the image as if I use `BLACKNESS` as the last argument for `BitBlt` it does display black rectangle with given dimensions. But generally nothing happens otherwise. Furthermore the script compiles without raising any error.

Comment: Where is the image file and how do you run the program?

Comment: IIRC, you can't just `BitBlt` from a Bitmap to a DC, you have to create a MemoryDC, Select the Bitmap into it, and BitBlt from there. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762783/bitblt-a-bitmap-onto-a-splash-screen).

Comment: You'll want to back up and get hold of Petzold's book, or similar. You are running before you can walk.

Comment: @user253751 i do run it using SCC from plato ide, my image file is in same dir

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i wish i had the book,  i looked through few YouTube tutorials but i cant find the full course on winapi, and that's the only reason i need c. if ya can recommend me some resource i would be grateful.

Comment: @KarstenKoop thanks ill look into it right now

Comment: We used to have the requirement for askers to demonstrate basic familiarity with the problem domain. I'm not sure why that was lifted. 'Questions' like this no longer have an appropriate reason to close them, though they should be.

Comment: @IInspectable i will close it then, im not sure how to though

Comment: To avoid confusion among readers you should not call C programs "scripts". C is not a script language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `BitBlt(dc,0,0,487,456,Bitmap,0,0,SRCPAINT);`

At this line you have tried to pass *bitmap handle* to *device context handle* parameter.

Note that `BitBlt` transfering bits from one device context to another. You would create another one device context for your bitmap, select bitmap into it and then do what you want to. For example:

```
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "neco.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,
      487, 456, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

  HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
  HDC hBitmapDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
  HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hBitmapDC, hBitmap);

  BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, 487, 456, hBitmapDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

  /* Don't forget to release resources that you've acquired */
  SelectObject(hBitmapDC, hOldBitmap)
  DeleteObject(hBitmap);
  DeleteDC(hBitmapDC);
  ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hDC);

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks @IInspectable for correcting me about GDI resource releasing.

Comment: Deleting a GDI resource while it is still selected into a device context isn't a supported operation. Deleting a device context while it still has objects selected into it that it doesn't own is likewise not a supported operation.

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you for enlightenment! I edited my answer. Is it correct now? I don't know how exactly I would release selected object from device context. What should I pass to second parameter of SelectObject()? NULL or strictly previously saved object?